# Thin gap I want to get rid of on my corner borders

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my picture have a corner border at the top left and bottom right. After achieveing this, I noticed that after a few seconds of loading the page there is a slight gap on my corner border. Here is an image of this gap. (I increased the width to show it more clearly).[image: Slight gap in my border corner]

Here is my html and css for this image:

```
<div class="picture">
    <img src="picture/MyPhoto.jpg" alt="My profile picture">
</div>
```

```
.picture {
    height: auto; 
    width: 35%; 
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(-30%, -30%);   
    animation: fadeIn 3s;    
}

.picture img {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    float: right;  
}

.picture::before,
.picture::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background-clip: padding-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.picture::before {
    top: -40px;
    left: 200px;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #000AFF, #DB00FF 50%, transparent 50%) 1; 
}
.picture::after {
    bottom: -550px;
    right: -130px;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top left,  #000AFF, #DB00FF 50%, transparent 50%) 1;
}
```

I tried to change some of the variables of the color gradient and the height and width but for some reason this thin gap appears.

Comment: you should not absolutely position multiple elements but rather use a single element and apply the form with the usage of `clip-path`. Or use an SVG altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The slight gap you are experiencing in your corner border might be due to the image's size and the border positioning. When you use border-image, the size of the pseudo-elements (::before and ::after) might not perfectly match the size of the image, resulting in a gap.

Here is your updated CSS code:

```
.picture {
  height: auto; 
width: 35%; 
position: relative;
top: 200px;
left: 55%;
transform: translate(-30%, -30%);   
animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

.picture img {
  max-width: 50%;
max-height: 50%;
float: right; 
}

.picture::before,
.picture::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

.picture::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #000AFF, #DB00FF 50%, transparent 50%) 1;
}

.picture::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to top left, #000AFF, #DB00FF 50%, transparent 50%) 1;
}
```

I have removed border-image size shorthand and used border-image-slice: 1 to ensure the gradient is applied uniformly across the border.
Then set width and height of ::before and ::after to 100% to match the image's dimensions.
By setting the width and height to 100%, the pseudo-elements will perfectly match the image's size, and the gap issue should be resolved.